# Can't able to access Model custom functions after adding values to queryset in View

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I created a Product model and added a custom def get_status_class to manage css classes for badges as per status and it works if I use all() in queryset but after using .values() with some particular field It's not working.

Model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):

PRODUCT_STATUS = (
('Planning','Planning'),
('In Progress','In Progress'),
('Final','Final'),
)

status = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=PRODUCT_STATUS)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('products:product_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

def get_status_class(self):
    status_class = ""
    if self.status == "Planning":
        status_class = "primary"
    elif self.status == "In Progress":
        status_class = "secondary"
    elif self.status == "Final":
        status_class = "success"
    return status_class

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

View.Py

```
class ProductListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
model = Product
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by(self.order_by)
    return queryset.values('status')
```

Template.py

```
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-{{product.get_status_class}}">{{ product.status }}</span>
```

product.get_status_class is not working if I add .values('status') in queryset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `values()`! That returns a list of dicts, not a queryset of instances. Just return the queryset from your `get_queryset` method.

Comment: True! it will if I do that. But its not a optimize way to do that because it return all fields for product table. Is that any way to do it in optimize way?

Comment: You could use the `only()` or `defer()` methods, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#defer). But this is usually an over-optimisation, as the warning on that page states. Unless you *know* you have a performance problem, you should just return the normal queryset.

Comment: (Also, not related to your question, but note that the `get_status_class` would be much better implemented using a dict.)

Comment: Yes I agree I am going to change get_status_class to dict. Thanks for help :)